# Сравнение дат в строке с данными

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Существует текстовый документ вот с такими данными:

```
08.05.02 0:16:43; 08.05.02 0:16:48;
```

Мне нужно вычесть одну дату из другой.

```cs
var result = Regex.Matches(Start, @"\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2} \d{1}\.\d{2}\.\d{2};");
foreach (Match item in result)
{
  Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(item.ToString(), "dd.MM.yy h.m.ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Comment: Документация: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=net-6.0 Пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871755/subtracting-two-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string text = "08.05.02 0:16:43; 08.05.02 0:16:48;";
var result = Regex.Matches(text, @"\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}");
DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(result[0].Value, "dd.MM.yy h:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(result[1].Value, "dd.MM.yy h:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date2 - date1);
```

Вывод в консоль

```
00:00:05
```